# How do i create a new Hive table from many Hive tables? I used JSON strings to create the original table and not sure how to create the new one

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

How do i create a new Hive table from many Hive tables?  I used JSON strings to create the original table and not sure how to create the new one.

```
create table Bank_F001_table as
select
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.text') as text,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.coordinates') as coordinates,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.user.location') as location,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.lang') as lang,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.user_mentions') as user_mentions,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.user.screen_name') as screen_name,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.user.name') as name,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.listed_count') as listed_count,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.in_reply_to_user_id_str') as in_reply_to_user_id_str
from Bank_F001;
```

Just wanted to add, i used UNION ALL to select attributes which worked out successfully. But I am unable to create a new table to use for other activities. Oddly, I also tried UNION (not with ALL) and Hive told me i need to use ALL. 
Here is my Select Code....

```
select *
from BMO_F016_table
union all
select *
from BMO_F017_table
union all
select *
from BMO_F018_table
union all
select *
from BMO_F054_table ) as large_table
group by screen_name
order by cnt desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it wasn't working but i figured it out... in case you're interested, here you go...

```
CREATE TABLE BMO_Table as
SELECT *
FROM BMO_F016_table
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM BMO_F017_table
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM BMO_F018_table
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM BMO_F054_table
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM BMO_F093_table
;
```